# How to manage IsCompleted value

Tags: c#, .net, task

I delete file like that. And need to know when it has been done to update UI (the list of the files in `ListBox`).

I am not sure how I can do it... Can I use `fi.DeleteAsync().IsCompleted`  value for that somehow?

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(currentPackage.FullPathFileName);          
fi.DeleteAsync().Wait();          
// Here I need some code to check when it is done. Any clues?

...

public static class FileExtensions
{
  public static Task DeleteAsync(this FileInfo fi)
  {
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fi.Delete());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `Wait`, you should use a continuation:

```
fi.DeleteAsync().ContinueWith(t => { /* update ui here */ }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSyncronizationContext()` ensures that the continuation runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

After deletion `fi.DeleteAsync().Wait();`

You can check if that file doesn't exist `if(!fi.exists)` then update your UI.

Comment: This will block the thread, though, so it is not a workable solution.